# Anyone have experience using version control software to manage a MediaWiki-based wiki?

Tags: svn, versioning, perforce, mediawiki

We use MediaWiki for user documentation. As the sole author, I can build and manage new versions of the wiki in order to support software version releases.

I'm looking for recommendations on how to manage the switch to a new MW instance (to coordinate with new software release). This is how I do it now:

MW instance at /wiki supports production (v1) software.
In a separate MW instance, I build /v2. When it's time to release a new software version, I simply backup v1 (MySQL database and HTML files), then copy v2 (MySQL database and HTML files) to the /wiki folder.

Is this practical? Can this be managed better/safer/more efficiently?
Thanks much, 
Evelyn

Answer (score 3):

Another approach might be to use wiki software like [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/) which has the ability to use real version control software on the back end to store the wiki pages (I use it with Git). With that, you could build v2 in another branch on another server, then when the time is right switch the main server from branch v1 to branch v2.